# Did first generation Pokemon games use event driven input or poll based input?

Tags: input, cocos2d

Did the first generation Pokemon games for gameboy poll for the d-pad state or was the input state done based on events?

I'm currently trying to implement a similar control and I'm interested in comparing my input with that of the gameboy and Pokemon.

I'm using SneakyInput and cocos2d.

Comment: I would expect they used polling; [it's the native way provided by the hardware](http://nocash.emubase.de/pandocs.htm#joypadinput), and there wasn't really a lot of processing power to spare with that ~4.2MHz CPU, especially not for a game as complex as this, so I think they'd want to keep it as simple as possible. Of course, you also have to remember that these games were [re-programmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pokémon_Red#Development) to make translation possible at all, so it is even possible that there is a difference between the "old" and the "new" version.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter weather it was written using input state or based on events, the only thing important is to have a good game control and that can be achived with both methods, also they can be very similar and user might not even feel any difference at all if it's implemented good enough.

Comment: Does it really matter?

Comment: @The Communist Duck: why short version of my comment had more votes than mine ? :(

Comment: @Gajet Because mine was short and concise and to the point.

Comment: @Gajet ...Also because your comment is just one long run-on-sentence.

Comment: @communistduck - yes, in trying to recreate gameboy controls on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really doesn't matter -- you can use either polling or event-based interrupts to simulate the other kind of input, so that decision is largely irrelevant in trying to mimic the characteristics of the input from older devices.

That said, you can find a lot of information about systems that old on emulation enthusiast websites ([this one](http://nocash.emubase.de/pandocs.txt), for example, contains a wealth of information about the hardware and memory-mapped registers uses by the GameBoy -- it's similar to the document linked in some of the comments, if not exactly the same in a different format).

To achieve emulation of a particular game's input characteristics you'd want to do it at a higher level -- taking into account things like how the game handles two opposing directional bits set for joystick input, for example. Many older games don't handle this well, because it is generally not possible to physically interact with the device fast enough or in such a fashion as to cause some of the potential states to exist. [This is how tool-assisted speed runners do some of their work](http://tasvideos.org/GameResources/NES/SuperMarioBros.html#ShootingFasterSmb1Smb2j).

You may want to scan through the [TASVideos resource page for Pokemon](http://tasvideos.org/GameResources/GBx/Pokemon.html) and see if maybe there are any control-related oddities you should be emulating if you really want that level of similarity to the game.

But I don't think it matters very much to the end result if you choose polling or not, even though that is generally what was used on the GameBoy.